# Integration of twitter posting in Blackberry+IllegalArguementException

Tags: blackberry, twitter

i am trying to embed twitter posting feature in my application.
i am using twitter api_me-1.8
i am able to reach the login screen(though most of the text is displayed as boxes- i am guessing that the text is in hindi/tamil as i am in india...), but as soon as i enter my credentials,i get taken to another page with some text in the top in boxes...
and more text in english below that(you can revoke access to any application...) ...then i  get an illeagalArguementException after a minute...

i tried to debug the application,

```
    public TwitterUiScreen(String wallMsg) {
    System.out.println("Twitter UI BEGINS!");
    setTitle("Twitter");
    this.wallMsg = wallMsg;
    BrowserContentManager browserMngr = new BrowserContentManager(0);
    RenderingOptions rendOptions = browserMngr.getRenderingSession()
            .getRenderingOptions();
    rendOptions.setProperty(RenderingOptions.CORE_OPTIONS_GUID,
            RenderingOptions.SHOW_IMAGES_IN_HTML, false);
    rendOptions.setProperty(RenderingOptions.CORE_OPTIONS_GUID,
            RenderingOptions.ENABLE_EMBEDDED_RICH_CONTENT, true);
    rendOptions.setProperty(RenderingOptions.CORE_OPTIONS_GUID,
            RenderingOptions.DEFAULT_FONT_FACE, true);
    rendOptions.setProperty(RenderingOptions.CORE_OPTIONS_GUID,
            RenderingOptions.DEFAULT_CHARSET_VALUE, true);
    rendOptions.setProperty(RenderingOptions.CORE_OPTIONS_GUID,
            RenderingOptions.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, true);
    /*
     * browserMngr.getRenderingSession().getRenderingOptions().setProperty(
     * RenderingOptions.CORE_OPTIONS_GUID,
     * RenderingOptions.DEFAULT_FONT_FACE, Font.getDefaultFont());
     */
    add(browserMngr);       
    OAuthDialogWrapper pageWrapper = new BrowserContentManagerOAuthDialogWrapper(browserMngr);
    pageWrapper.setConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
    pageWrapper.setConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
    pageWrapper.setCallbackUrl(CALLBACK_URL);
    pageWrapper.setOAuthListener(this);
    pageWrapper.login();
}
```

i had breakpoints upto the last line, and all of them were hit, with no problems...
but as soon as i logged in, i hit the exception.( i think it was in this page:-
BrowserContentManagerOAuthDialogWrapper.java (version 1.1 : 45.3, super bit)
after which i get to a third screen.

the comment was barely legible- so i thought i might as well add the code over here:

```
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-twitter";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "callback";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME+ "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
private final String CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL;
```

i managed to get the source and attach it to the jar file. the exception that the BrowserContentManagerOAuthDialogWrapper.java throws is:: Protocol not found: net.rim.device.cldc.io.x-oauthflow-twitter.Protocol
in this method::

```
protected void loadUrl(final String url, final byte[] postData, 
    final Event event) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                HttpConnection conn = getConnection(url);
                //
                if (postData != null) {
                    conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
                    conn.setRequestProperty(
                        "Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    conn.setRequestProperty(
                        "Content-Length", String.valueOf(postData.length));
                    //
                    OutputStream out = conn.openOutputStream();
                    out.write(postData);
                    out.close();
                }
                //
                browserManager.setContent(
                    conn, renderingListenerOAuth, event);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: What is your "CALLBACK_URL"? If that doesn't exist as a function, then when you log in, you'll get that type of error (i.e. ArgumentException).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

feel like hitting myself.
my clients had told us that the twitter posting was not working...
so i assumed that it did not work.
 for some reason, it does not work in the simulator- but seems to work fine on the device.

the clients have assumed that it does not work, as after we try logging in, it takes too long to post, and displays the third screen for about 20 seconds, and they seem to have clicked back early, deciding that posting did not work.

now i need to figure out a way to post a message on the third screen asking the user to wait for the post to be successful.